# Error al cortar el eje de un barplot

Tags: r

Tengo esta matriz, la cual quiero representar los valores en un histograma.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b1tIyDM977jIHivArAJh3sygPOEubk8Z/view?usp=sharing

Para ello ejecuté el siguiente código:

```
      n <- 46
      palette <- distinctColorPalette(n)

      #barplot
      barplot(t(as.matrix(my.df_total[, 2:20])), 
              beside = TRUE,
              names.arg = my.df_total$Mes,
              legend = TRUE,
              col = palette,
              ylab = "number of individuals",
              xlab = "Distribución temporal",
              ylim=c(0,800),
              las=2,
              args.legend = list( x = "topright", ncol = 2))
```

Estos valores hacen que obtenga este histograma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual aparece el eje y distorsionado por una barra del histograma que llega a 800 y luego por dos barras del histograma que llegan alrededor de 400. Me gustaría realizar dos roturas del eje para que se pueda ver el histograma perfectamente. Sin embargo no puedo cortar el eje con este código, que lo intenté para la primera rotura:

```
         gap.barplot(t(as.matrix(my.df_total[, 2:20])),gap=c(400,700),xlab="Index",ytics=c(0,300,600,700),
        ylab="Group values",horiz=FALSE,main="Barplot with gap")
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?

Además me gustaría eliminar el espacio entre los elementos de la leyenda.
¿Cómo podría realizar este cambio?

Muchas gracias de antemano.